# How can I dynamically add marked words in Transloco for translations like in i18n?

Tags: angular, internationalization, transloco

Is there a way to move dynamically the marked words to be translated in transloco ?

I mean like i18n, all the words with i18n should be added dynamically in the translation file, i would like to see if there is a way to attend the same in transloco too

Comment: How do you dynamically add marked words with angular i18n ? What do you mean by marked words ?